# Formula doesn't work when cell value is changed

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am working with POI Excel and I have this scenario:

Through this line code I change the A3 value, which is a drop list:

```
sheet.getRow(2).getCell(0).setCellValue(uf);
```

This part is working correct, I already verified that the cell value is been changed.

The bad part is this:

E7 has this formula: =CONCATENATE($A$3;D7)

So, when I change the A3 value using:

```
sheet.getRow(2).getCell(0).setCellValue(uf);
```

The E7 value should be changed through the formula, but this is not working.

I don't know how to dynamically change the cell value using the formula in java.

I thought that this should work by itself. As if I had manually changed the A3 value.

Comment: It shouldn't work that way. Use clearAllCachedResultValues(); Look https://stackoverflow.com/a/60559846/715269

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Apache POI, Excel formulas aren't automatically recalculated when a value changes.

When you are finished changing the values of any cells referenced in formulas, create a `FormulaEvaluator` and tell it to evaluate all formulas with [the `evaluateAll` method](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/FormulaEvaluator.html#evaluateAll()).

```
sheet.getWorkbook().getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();
```

Or you can force Excel to re-calculate formulas upon opening by setting the appropriate flag with [`setForceFormulaRecalculation` on the `Workbook`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#setForceFormulaRecalculation(boolean)).

```
sheet.getWorkbook().setForceFormulaRecalculation(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would advice to do

```
evaluator.clearAllCachedResultValues()
```

before any operation with evaluator if not created just now.

Javadoc:

```
/**
 * Should be called whenever there are changes to input cells in the evaluated workbook.
 * Failure to call this method after changing cell values will cause incorrect behaviour
 * of the evaluate~ methods of this class
 */
```

With that line before evaluation evaluator works correctly even on erroneous formulae.